Problem with rendering image pulled from indexedDB on front
So, I am making flashcards app on web, and its my first time using IndexedDB and BLOBs. At first i tried to do something by myself but it was total crap and then with some help of ai i came up with something like this
<body>
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card-front">

        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="difficulties">
        <div class="first-stage">
            <div class="cards-left">
                ...
            </div>
            <button class="show-answer">Show answer</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-stage" style="display: none;">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>

It is my html and i have such script to it
<script>        
        let db;
        const dbName = "FlashcardsDB";
        const dbVersion = 4;
        const request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
        request.onerror = (event) => {
            console.error("Database error: " + event.target.error);
        };
        request.onsuccess = (event) => {
            db = event.target.result;
            loadCards();
        };
        const cardFront = document.querySelector('.card-front');
        const cardBack = document.querySelector('.card-back');
        const firstStage = document.querySelector('.first-stage');
        const secondStage = document.querySelector('.second-stage');
        const showAnswerBtn = document.querySelector('.show-answer');
        const difficultyBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.second-stage button');

        let cards = [];
        let currentCardIndex = 0;

        function loadCards() {
            const transaction = db.transaction(["cards"], "readonly");
            const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("cards");
            const request = objectStore.getAll();
            request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                cards = event.target.result;
                if (cards.length > 0) {
                    displayCard(cards[currentCardIndex]);
                } else {
                    console.log("No cards found");
                    cardFront.innerHTML = "No cards available";
                    cardBack.innerHTML = "";
                }
            };

            request.onerror = (event) => {
                console.error("Error loading cards:", event.target.error);
                cardFront.innerHTML = "Error loading cards";
                cardBack.innerHTML = "";
            };
        }

        function parseContent(content) {
            return content.replace(/^"|"$/g, '').replace(/""/g, '"');
        }

        function displayCard(card) {
            cardFront.innerHTML = parseContent(card.front_content);
            cardBack.innerHTML = parseContent(card.back_content);
            cardBack.style.display = 'none';
            firstStage.style.display = 'block';
            secondStage.style.display = 'none';
            loadImages();
        }

        function loadImages() {
            const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
            console.log('Number of images found:', images.length);
            images.forEach((img, index) => {
                const fileName = img.getAttribute('src');
                console.log(`Image ${index + 1} filename:`, fileName);
                const transaction = db.transaction(["images"], "readonly");
                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("images");
                const request = objectStore.index("file_name").get(fileName);
                request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                    const imageData = event.target.result;
                    console.log(`Image data for ${fileName}:`, imageData);
                    if (imageData && imageData.image_data) {
                        let blob;
                        if (imageData.image_data instanceof Blob) {
                            blob = imageData.image_data;
                        } else if (imageData.image_data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
                            blob = new Blob([imageData.image_data], { type: imageData.mime_type });
                        } else if (imageData.image_data.data) {
                            blob = new Blob([imageData.image_data.data], { type: imageData.mime_type });
                        } else {
                            console.error(`Unable to create Blob for ${fileName}`);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (img.src.startsWith('blob:')) {
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
                        }
                        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        console.log(`Image ${fileName} loaded successfully`);
                        img.onload = function() {
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
                        };
                    } else {
                        console.error(`No image data found for ${fileName}`);
                    }
                };
                request.onerror = (event) => {
                    console.error(`Error loading image ${fileName}:`, event.target.error);
                };
            });
        }

        showAnswerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            cardBack.style.display = 'flex';
            firstStage.style.display = 'none';
            secondStage.style.display = 'flex';
        });

        difficultyBtns.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                currentCardIndex = (currentCardIndex + 1) % cards.length;
                displayCard(cards[currentCardIndex]);
            });
        });

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        });    
    </script>

It pulls out data correctly i assume as those are my console logs
Number of images found: 2
test:198 Image 1 filename: drawing-964f20c9029e0c58c36ace472991e210b0239061.png
test:198 Image 2 filename: paste-04c433989b80d578328a067fbfefd4b579e4c82c.png
test:204 Image data for drawing-964f20c9029e0c58c36ace472991e210b0239061.png:
{image_id: 35, image_data: {…}, mime_type: 'image/png', file_name: 'drawing-
964f20c9029e0c58c36ace472991e210b0239061.png', category: 'Nadciśnienie tętnicze'}

test:221 Image drawing-964f20c9029e0c58c36ace472991e210b0239061.png loaded successfully
test:204 Image data for paste-04c433989b80d578328a067fbfefd4b579e4c82c.png: 
{image_id: 71, image_data: {…}, mime_type: 'image/png', file_name: 'paste-
04c433989b80d578328a067fbfefd4b579e4c82c.png', category: 'Nadciśnienie tętnicze'}

test:221 Image paste-04c433989b80d578328a067fbfefd4b579e4c82c.png loaded successfully

Here is the thing, my front_content and back_content is stored as a html code
front_content: '"<img src=""drawing-964f20c9029e0c58c36ace472991e210b0239061.png""  back_content: '"<img src=""paste-04c433989b80d578328a067fbfefd4b579e4c82c.png"">"'
and it should be propagated with images from indexedb that has same names. My code generates such html code instead
<div class="cards"> <div class="card-front"><img src="blob:http://localhost:3000/c87ee4e0-9a4d-481e-87ff-fc48122ed507" class="drawing"></div> <div class="card-back" style="display: none;"><img src="blob:http://localhost:3000/6d68e5dc-4a90-4106-8fba-9e0c73d756fc"></div> </div>
Only thing rendered on my page is image placeholder, please help.
